# Quick way to view previous clip in Premiere's Source window?

Tags: premiere

Sometimes I'm viewing a clip in the Source window, in Premiere.  Then I open a different clip in the Source window.  Is there a way to quickly get back to the previous clip, without having to burrow through the Project folders again?

Answer (score 1):

I just found it by accident. Hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to go to the source viewer window, and hit it again to cycle through the previously opened clips. There's no display to tell you which clips are in the queue, other than right-clicking on the viewer tab, and the order seems to be alphabetical rather than chronological, so you might have to hit the shortcut a number of times.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure Premiere doesn't have the capability you described.

The only way I know to make searching through the project folders a bit easier is to use Prelude (assuming you have access to it as a part of Creative Cloud) to rename all your files easily. Prelude can add an incrementing number to the front or back of the name of each clip, which can make it easier to find out which clip you just viewed (if you're watching Clip 005, then Clip 004 was the one before it).